# Reverse tethering from ubuntu 15.10 to android 4.0.4

Tags: android, ubuntu, reverse, tethering

I am using ubuntu 15.10 and android 4.0.4. I googled a lot how to reverse tether from ubuntu to android but couldn't find any reasonable answers. So how can i share my ethernet connection on my ubuntu to android? i know i should create a new wifi hotspot from my pc and set it to "shared to other devices" but the wifi hotspot is NOT visible in my android phone! Also creating a wireless network with setting "infrastructure" to "ap" mode did not work for me.
Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [**`hostapd`**](https://w1.fi/hostapd/).

This documentation for Ubuntu looks like it'd get you going, but you'll probably have to make a few tweaks, like `wlan0` will be `eth0`. `wlan1` would be the wireless adapter that is broadcasting to your phone.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessAccessPoint